# Bootstrap: why tab content area is pushed down away from tabs?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am learning Bootstrap. I have a strange situation in which tab content is pushed down away from tabs.

The page layout is simple. A menu is floated to left and the main content have a left margin to hold the menu.

In the main content area, I have a Bootstrap tab component.

However, the tab's content area is pushed vertically down. Here is the code:

```
<div style="width: 100px; float:left;height:300px;background-color:red;">
    left
</div>

<div style="margin-left: 120px; background-color: pink">

    <div class="tabbable">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
          <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
          <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

See it at http://jsfiddle.net/dDNBS/7/

I cannot figure out why. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your js fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/dDNBS/7/ .

Code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">        
     <div style="background-color:red;height:150px;" class="span3">
       left
     </div>
     <div style="background-color: pink;height:150px;" class="span9">
          <div class="tabbable">
             <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
             </ul>
             <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
              </div>
             </div>
          </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since you are using bootstrap you have to use span class for maintaining div's inline. Default bootstrap grid layout has a division of 12 spans, so here i split the left side by span3 and right tabbable by span9 and put inside a row class to fit into the container class.

Comment: prem, I understand spand3 and span9. Why do i have to use Bootstrap grid in this particular case? Again, thanks!

Comment: the thing is the your left side red div's height affects the right side pink div, but here you asked for your own area widths then customize and download bootstrap at  http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html

Comment: i have to use my layout code, nor bootstrap's default or custom layout code. i am simply puzzled by "left side red div's height affects the right side pink div". what does this happen in the first place? thanks.

Comment: Since because the red div heght is applied all over the span of the page, so we have to say explicitly that pink div is another div belong to separate span and its inline to the previous div. So the Solution is http://jsfiddle.net/2qbtV/